# speechSynthesis not working in react-native-webview on ios 13

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech, ios13, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview to show generated html and triggering window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance) on ios 13 but speaking is not staring.
React-native : 0.60v
code Sample:

var synth = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(content);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(synth);

Comment: First, make sure that content isn't blank! console.log(content); If that's OK maybe you have to get the voices first: `const voices  = speechSynthesis.getVoices();` and assign a voice to the utterance: `synth.voice = voices[0];` and `synth.lang = voices[0].lang;` then run the speak command.

Comment: no its not working on iphone 11pro with ios 13

Comment: Please add your full code and html.

Comment: synth = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(content);
                const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                speech_state = 1;
                lastCall = callback;
                try {
                    synth.voice = voices[0];
                    synth.lang = voices[0].lang;
                    window.speechSynthesis.speak(synth);
                } catch(e) {
                    post("Speak error = " + e);
                }

Comment: I am using this on dynamically generated html and trigger this for one paragraph

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand a problem when the code isn't available so I can't help you.